# Getting average difference between two dates in minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get avg receiving time in minutes for each outlet.

I have tow tables Orders and ReceivedOrders.

**Orders**

```
OrderID OutletID OrderDate
1       1        2017-04-10 17:04:41.000
```

**ReceivedOrders**

```
ReceivingID OrderID ReceivingDate
1           1       2017-04-10 17:06:31.000
```

i have tried the below query but its reruns zero as avg receiving time

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT        Outlets.OutletName , avg(datediff(MM, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) as Receive
FROM          dbo.Orders INNER JOIN
              dbo.Outlets ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID INNER JOIN
              dbo.ReceivedOrders ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReceivedOrders.OrderID 
group by dbo.Outlets.OutletName
```

**Output**

```
OutletName Receive
Outlet1    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use datediff with millisecond option:

```
select Outlets.OutletName,
    avg(datediff(ms, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) / 60000 as Receive
from dbo.Orders
inner join dbo.Outlets on dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID
inner join dbo.ReceivedOrders on dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReceivedOrders.OrderID
group by dbo.Outlets.OutletName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing *exactly* what you are specifying.  You are getting the date diff in *months*, not *minutes*.

When using date parts, just spell out the full name of the date part:

```
SELECT ol.OutletName,
       avg(datediff(minute, o.OrderDate, ro.ReceivingDate)) as Receive
FROM dbo.Orders o INNER JOIN
     dbo.Outlets ol
     ON o.OutletID = ol.OutletID INNER JOIN
     dbo.ReceivedOrders ro
     ONo.OrderID = ro.OrderID 
GROUP BY ol.OutletName;
```

The above counts minute boundaries between two values.  You may want parts of minutes, in which case I would use a smaller unit.  Milliseconds are definitely an option, but they can overflow pretty easily if the dates are even a few months apart.  So, you might really want something more like this:

```
SELECT ol.OutletName,
       avg(datediff(second, o.OrderDate, ro.ReceivingDate)/60.0) as minutesToReceive
FROM dbo.Orders o INNER JOIN
     dbo.Outlets ol
     ON o.OutletID = ol.OutletID INNER JOIN
     dbo.ReceivedOrders ro
     ONo.OrderID = ro.OrderID 
GROUP BY ol.OutletName;
```

Note the use of `60.0` rather than `60` to force non-integer arithmetic.